# Trouble displaying JSON data from music api

Tags: javascript, json, api

I am having trouble to display the top tracks of a searched artist using the LastFM api to get data. The api returns an object toptracks. I would like to grab details about each of the top tracks from that api data.

I am not sure if I am on the right track. Can someone take a look and let me know if I am doing something wrong?

Sample data from api:

```
{
    "toptracks": {
        "track": [{
                "name": "Best I Ever Had",
                "playcount": "3723918",
                "listeners": "1086968",
                "mbid": "00bde944-7562-446f-ad0f-3d4bdc86b69f",
                "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Drake/_/Best+I+Ever+Had",
                "streamable": "0",
                "artist": {
                    "name": "Drake",
                    "mbid": "b49b81cc-d5b7-4bdd-aadb-385df8de69a6",
                },
                "@attr": {
                    "rank": "1"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Forever",
                "playcount": "1713492",
                "listeners": "668998",
                "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Drake/_/Forever",
                "streamable": "0",
                "artist": {
                    "name": "Drake",
                    "mbid": "b49b81cc-d5b7-4bdd-aadb-385df8de69a6",
                },
                "@attr": {
                    "rank": "2"
                }
            }
}
```

```
function renderTracks(trackArray) {

    function createHTML(track){
        return `<h1>${track.name}</h1>
                <h2>${track.artist[0]}</h2>
                <h3>${toptracks[1].rank}</h3> 
                <h3>${track.playcount}</h3>`;

    };

    trackHTML = trackArray.map(createHTML);

    return trackHTML.join("");

};





    var searchString = $(".search-bar").val().toLowerCase();
    var urlEncodedSearchString = encodeURIComponent(searchString); 

    const url = "lastFMwebsite" 

    axios.get(url + urlEncodedSearchString).then(function(response) {
    // createHTML.push(response.data.track);
    // $(".tracks-container").innerHTML = renderTracks(response.data.track);
    // comented out old code above 
    createHTML.push(response.toptracks.track);
    $(".tracks-container").innerHTML = renderTracks(response.toptracks.track);


})
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON, the braces don't match properly.

Comment: Well, there's only one top track, so grab the data about that track?

Comment: `response.data.track` should be `response.toptracks.track`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've notice that you have not parsed the response:

```
axios.get(url + urlEncodedSearchString).then(function(response) {
    var parsed = JSON.parse(response);
    $(".tracks-container").innerHTML = renderTracks(parsed.toptracks.track)
});
```

Another correction that I can suggest is to change the `track.artist[0]` to `track.artist["name"]` once this property returns an object instead of an array.
And about this: `<h3>${toptracks[1].rank}</h3>`. You will be not able to access that property because at your function you are providing just the `track`property.
In this case you have two options: provide the whole response array or add a new parameter providing this.

```
function renderTracks(trackArray) {/**...*/};
//...
$(".tracks-container").innerHTML = renderTracks(parsed.toptracks)
```

Or

```
function renderTracks(trackArray, toptracks) {/**...*/};
//...
$(".tracks-container").innerHTML = renderTracks(parsed.toptracks.track, parsed.toptracks)
```

I hope this can help you :)

Comment: Thank you very much! That was very helpful and I was able to get the track properties to display. I will continue working on getting the rank to display. I am not sure how to ask this, but If for example there was another property one level deeper than the rank, would I need to add a 3rd parameter?

Comment: Not necessarily. My suggetion was to ilustrate how you could access that property. The best thing to do actually would be to provide the whole array into the function and, with that, you'll be able to access all properties that you wan inside the function. [a quickly example about JSON and its properties](https://www.mkyong.com/javascript/how-to-access-json-object-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

Your input JSON is not valid. You'll need to format it correctly. Once the data is correct:

```
createHTML.push(response.toptracks.track[0])

or

let i = 0;
for(; i < response.toptracks.track.length; i++){
 createHTML.push(response.toptracks.track[i]);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I just updated the JSON with the correct formatting.For the template literal part up top, would it follow the same process as your exmaple? Like if I wanted to display just the track name, would it be `${toptracks.track.name}` ?